# if an RNN was trained on $y=10x^3+5x+1$ will it work with for example $y = 2x^3 + x -5$ as well?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

If we trained an RNN type of neural network (RNN, LSTM, GRU, etc) on a set of datapoints that were generated for example from a function such as $y = 10x^3 + 5x + 1$ , and then tried to use datapoints generated from a similar function such as $y = 2x^3 + x - 5$ , would that still work? or are these considered to completely different functions?
Should the multiplicants be the same everywhere?

Comment: This sounds like an experiment that you could readily carry out. What happens when you train the model on the first function and test it on the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem falls in the category of meta-learning, for which there are many proposed methods. A key paper in this topic is the MAML (pronounced "mammal") paper by Chelsea Finn, Pieter Abbeel, Sergey Levine, "[Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning for Fast Adaptation of Deep Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03400)".

The core concept of MAML is that the method of training allows models to rapidly adapt to new tasks with only a small amount of examples.

The gist of the paper is that the ordinary way of training a neural network doesn't adapt well to a new problem which is similar to the one it was trained on. The authors use the example of sine waves with different amplitudes, but a cubic function with different coefficients seems like the same idea, in the sense that the MAML network may be able to quickly adapt from one cubic function to another.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciae this. at first I was scheptical, then I recalled that NNs are basically universal approximators, in the questions assumption, the network should learn $\theta$s so that it can approximate properly and $\theta$ are multiplicants here. so basically the weights are different for both formulas, since the functions are completely different things. and that wouldnt work. 
Then I read your answer, and then I figured out your point! the two functions are similar, but not the same, so using a proper method, network should be able to perform well. :)

Comment: Yes, the key idea is *quickly adapting* from a small number of examples of the new function. Whereas an ordinary network won't adapt quickly, a MAML network can because of its specialized training procedure.

Comment: Thanks, that was really good :)